# addventlistenenera

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones

Buenas estoy usando los eventlisteners de forma global usando el siguiente código
al ingresar el segundo EventListener me manda un error en la consola.
gracias por su ayuda

```javascript
//eventListeners();
///las variables globales se ponen aca
var listaProyectos = document.querySelector('ul#proyectos');

function eventListeners() {
  //boton para crear proyecto
  document.querySelector('.crear-proyecto a').addEventListener('click', nuevoProyecto);

  document.querySelector('.nueva-tarea').addEventListener('click', agregarTarea);


}
```

Comment: Tienes que ser más específico con tu pregunta.
¿Cuáles son las funciones **agregarTarea** **nuevoProyecto**?
¿Qué error de consola te manda?
¿Cómo es el HTML que estás usando?

Te recomiento visitar el recorrido para saber [cómo hacer preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Sigue las indicaciones de los compañeros,
Pero para que vayas viendo como va:

```
var listaProyectos = document.querySelector('ul#proyectos');
```

Si aquí estás llamando a elemento del HTML por su Id, el # va al principio '#ulproyectos'
Sino no te lo va a reconocer.
Luego en los listeners, éstos los vinculas a 'clases' no a id, es porque tienes una plantilla hecha de estilo para usar?. Igualmente que hace la función nuevoProyecto y agregarTarea?
Creas elementos html de forma dinámica?
Debes pasar más información.